# image chooser javafx android mobile

Tags: java, android, javafx, gluon-mobile, javafxports

How to choose image from android directory/gallery in `javafxmobile-plugin`. I am unable to choose files like `images` in android device. when i open directory app hangs and suddenly close. Any help???

I already have tried in android device using javafx `file chooser` && `directory choose` but notthing helps. also i found no helpful post on the `stackoverflow`

my `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.16'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
}

mainClassName = 'com.maqboolsolutions.directorychooserandroid.App'

ext.CHARM_DOWN_VERSION = "1.0.0"

dependencies { 
    compile "com.gluonhq:charm-down-common:$CHARM_DOWN_VERSION"
    desktopRuntime "com.gluonhq:charm-down-desktop:$CHARM_DOWN_VERSION"
    androidRuntime "com.gluonhq:charm-down-android:$CHARM_DOWN_VERSION"

    compile 'com.airhacks:afterburner.mfx:1.6.3'
}

jfxmobile {
    javafxportsVersion = '8.60.11'

    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'

        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
        }

        dexOptions {
            javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        }
    }
}
```

`.java` codding:

```
@FXML
private void btnCooserOnAction(ActionEvent event) {
    DirectoryChooser directoryChooser = new DirectoryChooser();

    Stage primaryStage = (Stage) stackPaneRoot.getScene().getWindow();

    File selectedDirectory = directoryChooser.showDialog(primaryStage);

    if (selectedDirectory == null) {
        lblPath.setText("No Directory selected");
    } else {
        lblPath.setText(selectedDirectory.getAbsolutePath());
    }
}
```

App not response. and close...

Comment: Why are you using Charm Down 1.0.0? Current version is 3.8.6, and goes in the `jfxmobile { downConfig {}}` block. See any of the samples [here](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples). Use `StorageService` for file access and storage, and `PicturesService` for accessing the gallery. See [javaDoc](http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/javadoc/5.0.2/com/gluonhq/charm/down/plugins/PicturesService.html)

Comment: Thanks for comments! I acctualy use `charm down 1.0.1` because i use only some codding from this library. like to know `platform` and so on. I am not using gluon-mobile because it's free version causes a `nag screen at startup` which i do not like. I used perfect javafx for front-end and `javafxmobile-plugin` to convert java program to android. If their any way to use `gluon` freely without any limitation or `nag screen`. Then i will be ready to use `gluon mobile`. Any idea???

Comment: I don't recommend at all using such an old version. Everything you may need (like `Platform`) is available as well from the latest Charm Down 3.8.6. See for instance this [sample](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples/blob/7581c254793f3675eacdbff0e5ff24c8eb873bde/gluon-SQLite/src/main/java/com/gluonhq/sqlite/GluonSQLite.java#L49). About the nag screen, you need a [icense](https://gluonhq.com/products/mobile/buy/) to get rid of it. There are [free licenses](https://gluonhq.com/programs/free-gluon-licenses/) for open source or students.

Comment: I an not a student noir a open source developer. I am a `CTO` in a small company called `Maqbool Solutions (SMC-Pvt) Ltd.`. My company not yet grow to puchase a very high payable license. So i can't use gluon. rather then makes such a things. Any confusion???

Comment: The license is only required when you deploy your application to the stores, in the meantime you can use Gluon Mobile with 100% of the features, and only this nag screen. And definitely it is not a "very high payable license", check the Indie tier for one developer.

Comment: but for a startup companies like in Pakistan it is a lot of burden...